# With Stripe, make an hold on a payment and confirm it when the subscription starts

Tags: stripe-payments

We are working on a service that can start a subscription later in the future: users say today they want the service, but it actually starts some days later.

We are now collecting the payment method through a `SetupIntent`, which allows the user to verify they own card, but it actually doesn't verify the credit availability. When we collected the payment method, we create a scheduled subscription with the verified payment method; then, when the subscription starts, Stripe uses that payment method to collect money.

It happens, sometimes, that users do not have enough credit to pay for the service when the subscription starts. Otherwise, it also happens that, when Stripe tries to get money, the customer's bank requires 3D-secure verification.
Since our subscriptions start at midnight, we would like to avoid having to involve users again in the payment process.

So, we thought: would it be possible to immediately collect the payment method through an hold on a `PaymentIntent` and confirm that hold only when the subscription starts? I can't find a way to do this with Stripe (don't know if it exists). It seems impossible, with Stripe, to generate a PaymentIntent (with `capture_method` set to `manual`) for a scheduled subscription.

Do you have some ideas on how we can avoid payment problems when the subscription starts?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this by first creating a `paymentIntent` with `setup_future_usage="off_session"` and `capture_method="manual"` to first place a hold and save the `paymentMethod`, and then, **only after capturing** this `paymentIntent`, creating a `subscription` using the newly saved `paymentMethod` with `billing_cycle_anchor` that equals your subscription's interval from now.

This way it's like your customer has paid for the first interval using the paymentIntent, but will be charged from the second interval using the subscriptions API, which allows you to cancel the hold on the first payment and not create a subscription if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Otherwise, it also happens that, when Stripe tries to get money, the
> customer's bank requires 3D-secure verification.

This shouldn't be the case if you complete any required 3DS authentication as a part of the [SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#confirm-the-setupintent) confirmation flow. Call [`confirmCardSetup`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_card_setup) whilst the user is present and that way the payment method is successfully verified and can be used to process [off-session payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#web-create-payment-intent-off-session) for your subscription as you need.

You can use Stripe to place a [hold on a card](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later), but this generally doesn't apply to the use case you've described.

Comment: We confirm the SetupIntent through stripe.confirmSetupIntent() (on Android}. It is confirmed correctly but, when the subscription starts after some hours, it goes to the status "past_due" after one hour from its beginning (we're using the Stripe's test card "4000 0027 6000 3184").

Comment: @Massimo I believe that card will always require authentication, regardless of whether it used with SetupIntents. Instead you should try this card: `4000 0025 0000 3155` when confirming your SetupIntent. There's an extensive list of 3DS testing cards [here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards).